# Replicate Fabric js Hue Rotation of an image to Python using OpenCv and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, fabricjs

I am currently working with image filtering and need to adjust the hue of an image using Python. I've been using Fabric.js to perform hue rotation, and the results are satisfactory, but the execution speed is very slow. So I want to replicate some of the image filtering functionality in Python. However, when attempting to achieve the same hue rotation effect in Python, I've encountered challenges that have led to discrepancies between the Python output and the Fabric.js output.

Here is a simplified version of my Python code.

```
def adjust_hue(image, hue_value):
    """
    changes the Hue of the image using the hue_value parameter and returns the adjusted image.
    The hue_value must be in range (-1, 1).
    """

    # Split the input image into the color channels (BGR) and alpha channel
    bgr_channels = image[:, :, :3]
    alpha_channel = image[:, :, 3]

    hue_value = (hue_value * 180) / 2

    # Convert BGR image to HSV color space
    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_channels, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Adjust the hue of the HSV image
    hsv_image[:, :, 0] = (hsv_image[:, :, 0] + hue_value) % 180

    # Convert the adjusted HSV image back to BGR color space
    bgr_adjusted = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_image, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

    # Merge the adjusted BGR channels with the original alpha channel
    result_image = np.dstack((bgr_adjusted, alpha_channel))

    return result_image

# ......
# thats how I am calling the function

rotation = 0.33333333333333333333333333333333 # Same as 60 in range -180 to 180
filtered_image = adjust_hue(image, rotation)


cv2.imwrite('merged.png', filtered_image)
```

As Fabric.js expects the hue in the range (-1, 1), so I kept The range of the hue_value as same as fabic.js. I am converting from (-1, 1) to (-180, 180).
Of course, I tried this `hue_value = (hue_value * 180)` formula to convert from (-1, 1) to (-180, 180), but don't know why it was not showing the output as expected. For example, if I pass 0.3333...... which is 60 in range (-180, 180), it will show the output as if I passed 120. So that's why I divided it by 2.

Note that my input image is in png format, so it has transparent ends.

The input image is as follows
[image]

The output image is
[image]

The expected(Fabric.js) output is
[image]

Although there is not a big difference between Python output image and fabric js output image but still a human eye can detect the difference easily. I ran  Absolute Error (AE) algorithm on various online websites and found that there is more than a 15% difference in various areas of the image. So could someone please guide me on how to achieve accurate hue rotation in Python, similar to what Fabric.js provides?

Packages I used

numpy==1.24.4
opencv-python==4.8.0.74

Comment: What is the meaning of hue between -1 and 1?  Is that -180 to 180 or 0 to 360 or what? You should define that.  Then why do you do `hue_value = (hue_value * 180) / 2`?  Is your input hue_value in the range -1 to 1 or 0 to 360 or what?  I am not sure I understand or you are doing the correct translation between -1 to 1 and 0 to 180 for OpenCV.  Please clarify

Comment: I just updated it.  I am converting from (-1, 1) to (-180, 180). I tried this `hue_value = (hue_value * 180)` formula to convert from (-1, 1) to (-180, 180), but don't know why it was not showing the output as expected. For example, if I pass 0.3333...... which is 60 in range (-180, 180), it will show the output as if I passed 120. So that's why I divided it by 2, and it shows almost close to the expected output.

Comment: But OpenCV uses hue in range 0 to 180, not -180 to 180.

Comment: I tried to convert from (-1, 1) to (0, 180) using the following formula, but I am not sure if I am right.

`normalized_hue = (hue_value + 1) * 90`
`

When I send 0.5 to the function this formula gives a pink image, but in fabric js 0.5 shows a green image. two results are entirely different.

Comment: What does -1 to 1 represent?  Is it -180 to 180 or 0 to 360 or -360 to 360 or something else?  You need to understand what -1 to 1 represents before you can do the conversion.  Please clarify that or point to some documentation that defines it.

Comment: What I find in the fabric.js documentation is "HueRotation value, from -1 to 1. the unit is radians". So that means -180/pi to 180/pi deg or -57 to 57 deg. So their hue rotation is restricted.  See http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.filters.HueRotation.html

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that the hue rotation unit in Fabic.js is in radians or -57 to 57 deg. But in the last line, you said that "their hue rotation is restricted". What did you mean by that? I did not get it. What should I do next?

Comment: Restricted to -57 to 57 as opposed to -180 to 180.